# Firefox extension listing on http-on-examine-response for responses with 200 status code only

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have an observer defined on http-on-examine-response as

```
httpRequestObserver = {

observe: function(request, aTopic, aData){

        if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response") {
             request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);

             var newListener = new TracingListener();
             request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);

             newListener.originalListener = request.setNewListener(newListener);

    }
}, 
QueryInterface: function(aIID){
    if (typeof Cc == "undefined") {
        var Cc = components.classes;
    }
    if (typeof Ci == "undefined") {
        var Ci = components.interfaces;
    }
    if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIObserver) ||
    aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
        return this;
    }

    throw components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;

},
};
```

I want to add the listener in only those cased where the response code of the reponse is 200.Basically what i am trying to accomplish is avoid 3xx reponses.But i am unable to read ResponseCode from the headers.How to get the response code here.

Thanks in advance for the help...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `httpChannel.responseStatus`, here is [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel).

So, change your `observe` function to

```
observe: function(request, aTopic, aData){
        if (aTopic !== 'http-on-examine-response') {
            return;
        }
        let httpChannel = request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
        if (httpChannel.responseStatus !== 200) {
            return;
        }

        // do your stuff...
        let traceableChannel = event.subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
        let newListener = new TracingListener();
        newListener.originalListener = traceableChannel.setNewListener(newListener);

    }
},
```